# Get specific post from CloudFirestore with React JS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So, I have a new problem. I have tried to solve this a couple of days without success.

I'm trying to learn react and has creating a reactjs-site where I showcasing videos.

First I had problem to get the ID from the query string, but sort of solved it.

The code in my video.js looks like this:

```
function getDataFromDB(props) {


const [times, setTimes] = useState([])
const db = firebase.firestore();


useEffect(() => {

    fire.firestore().collection('videoEvent').onSnapshot((snapshot) => { //time is the db name
        const newTimes = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()

        }))

        setTimes(newTimes)
    })

}, [])
return times
 }

 const Video = (props) => {

const videoEvent = getDataFromDB()

const vidId = props.match.params.id;
console.log(vidId)
const { project } = props;
    return (

      <div className='div1080'>
        <div className='flex-container'>
            {videoEvent.map((videoEvent) =>
                 <div key={videoEvent.id} className='item' ><img className='imagevideo' src={photo} alt='hej' />
                  <br /> {videoEvent.Author} {videoEvent.Price} 
                  {props.match.params.id}
                  <Link to={'video/' + videoEvent.id}>{videoEvent.eventTitle}</Link>
                </div>


               )}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Video
```

So now it is looping all the posts, that works fine, but I just want to show a specific post, with the ID from 'props.match.params.id'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To access a single document for which you know the ID, see the documentation on [getting a single document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) and [getting realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). Based on that:

```
fire.firestore().collection('videoEvent').doc(props.match.params.id).onSnapshot((doc) => {
    const newTimes = [{
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data()
    ])

    setTimes(newTimes)
})
```

You'll need to pass the ID to `getDataFromDB`, which you seem to have forgotten:

```
const videoEvent = getDataFromDB(props)
```